# Running a function right after each context switch, in C under windows-XP

Tags: c, multithreading, windows-xp, context-switch

I'm programming a multithreading application in C under windows-XP.
I'm looking for a way to run a function, right after each context-switch between threads of the application (and just before the starting of the new thread).
To be more precise, I want to assign, in a certain memory-address, a different value, depending on to which thread I got into.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for thread local storage?

Answer (score 1):

> Running a function right after each context switch

This is something doomed from the beginning: you do not have control over context switches. What would happen if the OS switches when your function was just called? And then switches back? Another execution?

If what you want is just having variables with a specific content for each thread, look into Thread Local Storage, as other suggested.

If what you need is fine-grained and absolute control over sub-process computations and scheduling, use [fibers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But this is NOT something you do with a light heart...

Comment: +1 Yeah - sounds like a useful function to have, but no OS supports it - there's a reason for that!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
I guess I'll find a workaround for the problem.